# highlight cells in column B that match column A

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I highlight a cell in Column B if it exists anywhere in Column A?

The cells list items in one environment (A) that I need to check if they exist in the other environment (B).

Currently I have them sorted A-Z, but can't figure out how to match and color the ones that match.

If it's not possible, I'd accept having a third column that puts a 1 or Y if it matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to highlight both columns, then Conditional Formatting>Highlight Cell Rules>Duplicate Values